# Rstudioにてlmer関数を使用したいが，lme4，lmerTest，mlmRevパッケージをインストールしても使用できません

Tags: r

Rstudioにて，線形階層モデルを行おうとしています。
昔，同様の処理をLme4パッケージのインストール，lmerライブラリの呼び出し，lmer関数の使用でできたと記憶しているのですが，lmerライラブリの呼び出しの時点でうまくいきません。

`library("lmer")`

> library("lmer") でエラー:  ‘lmer’ という名前のパッケージはありません

資料を調べ，lmer関数を使用した人が，lme4，lmerTest，mlmRevのパッケージをインストールしていることを確認したのですが，実践してみると，lmer関数の使用までいずれもうまくいきませんでした。
念のため，パッケージ名と同様のライラブリ名で呼び出しもしましたがエラーがでました(念のため，使用したいのはlmer関数のみ)。

`library("lme4")`

> エラー: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> ‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません
> 追加情報:  警告メッセージ:
> パッケージ ‘lme4’ はバージョン 3.5.3 の R の下で造られました
> `lmer(Y ~ x1 +x2 (ID|factor), data=data)`
> lmer(Y ~ x1 +x2  でエラー:
> 関数 "lmer" を見つけることができませんでした

`library("lmerTest")`

> library("lmerTest") でエラー:
> ‘lmerTest’ という名前のパッケージはありません

`library("mlmRev")`

> 要求されたパッケージ lme4 をロード中です
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> ‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません
> エラー:  パッケージ ‘lme4’ をロードできませんでした
> 追加情報:  警告メッセージ:
> 1:  パッケージ ‘mlmRev’ はバージョン 3.5.3 の R の下で造られました
> 2:  パッケージ ‘lme4’ はバージョン 3.5.3 の R の下で造られました
> `lmer(Y ~ x1 +x2 (ID|factor), data=data)`
> lmer(Y ~ x1 +x2  でエラー:
> 関数 "lmer" を見つけることができませんでした

お気づきの点教えて頂けましたら幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

まず, `lmer` というパッケージはありません. おそらく資料を書いた方は `lme4` というパッケージに含まれる `lmer()` 関数を使っているのだと思います. よって `lmer4` をロードする必要があるのですが, そちらのエラーを見る限り `lme4` が依存しているパッケージが存在しないため `lme4` の読み込みに失敗しているのが原因に見えます.

以下のコマンドで `lme4` をインストールし直してみてください

```
install.packages("lme4", dependencies = T)
```

Comment: 有難うございます。ご提示頂いたコマンドでlme4をインストールし直しました。 library(lme4) lmer(Y ~ x1 +x2 (ID|factor), data=data) このあとは，上のコマンドで回るはずでしょうか？ 2行目に，最初の投稿と同様のエラー文章が表示されました。詳しく教えて頂けましたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します

Comment: 「2行目に，最初の投稿と同様のエラー文章が表示」とはどういう意味でしょうか? 依然として `‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません` と表示されるのならインストールに失敗しています. インストール時のメッセージをよく確認してみてください. もしくは先に `nloptr` 単体でインストールが成功するかを確認してみてください

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。

`library("lme4")
 エラー: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
  ‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません 
 追加情報:  警告メッセージ: 
 パッケージ ‘lme4’ はバージョン 3.5.3 の R の下で造られました`

nloptr単体でインストールすることはできましたが，その後も依然としてこのようなエラーが返ってきます。lme4のインストールに失敗しているようです。

Comment: `nloptr` のインストールに成功しているのなら, `lme4` の読み込みでそのようなエラーはでないと思います. 両パッケージで `install.package` を実行した時のログに `installation of package ‘XXXX’ had non-zero exit status` のようなメッセージは出ていませんか? これが出ていればインストールは失敗しています. そうでなければ, (あまりない事象ですが) 何らかの理由でRが参照できないフォルダにインストールされている可能性があります

Comment: カレントディレクトリの設定がRstudioがインストールされたフォルダから動いていたことが問題だったようです。Rstudioのフォルダに指定しなおしたところ，無事にlme4がインストールでき，統計モデルの解析が動きました。重ね重ねご丁寧に教えて下さり有難うございました。